# Beginner Question about the definition of finite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hi this question is in regard to a part of chapter 7 in Daniel Velleman's book "*How to Prove it*". I just began to learn about infinite sets and such and there is one part that confuses me. It starts as"Definition: Suppose A and B are sets. We say A is equinemrous with B if there is a function f: A-->B that is one to one and onto. We write A~B to indicate A is equinemrous to B. For each natural number *n* , Let I$_n$={i $\in$Z$^+$| i$\le$ n}.

A set A is called finite if there is a natural number n such that 
 I$_n$~A. Otherwise A is infinite".

I understand that there must be a bijection of A onto B for the sets to be equinemours. What I am confused about is the part where it says Let I$_n$={i $\in$Z$^+$| i$\le$ n}.  a set A is called finite if there is a natural n such that I$_n$~A. What does it mean by this? What is another way to think about this. I think just another explanation could help.

Thanks a lot everyone,

Comment: You should realize by now that formulas in your posts don't look as good as formulas in other people's posts. Why so? [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).

Comment: Im not sure, sorry that it is not up to your standards? Maybe you could let me know what is wrong with it so that I could actually change it.

Comment: You were shown exactly what needed to be done already. Look at your previous questions: they were edited by different people, each of whom spent their time putting your questions into better shape.

Comment: Okay, what part of the question did you find unclear? I did not realize you must be perfect at writing equations to post a question on this site.

Comment: Now you know it. :)

Comment: I am very confused - why the downvotes?

Comment: @LearningMath: You don't have to to be perfect at writing equations, and I personally think your equations are fine as is, even though they could be "better". In any case, I highly recommend learning how to use LaTex in your posts - it takes some time but once you learn it you are able to write much faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is a set of physical objects in the room with you, and you have a bijection $f:I_{42}\to A$. You can point to $f(1)$, which is an element of $A$, and say "one" to yourself. You can then point to $f(2)$, which is a different element of $A$, and say "two" to yourself. Continuing, eventually you point to $f(42)$, say "forty-two", and you're done.

Conversely, if you don't know how many objects are in $A$, you can count them by pointing to an object at random and saying "one". Point to a different object and say "two". In this way, you will build up a function $f:I_{42}\to A$, which will be a bijection.

In other words, having a bijection $f:I_n\to A$ is the same as literally counting $A$ and concluding that there are $n$ elements. A set is finite if you can count it and stop at some natural number $n$.

Answer (score 3):

When Velleman writes 
$$I_n = \{i \in \mathbb Z^+ |\ i \le n\}$$
he is using set-builder notation to describe a certain set: The set of positive integers, ($i \in \mathbb Z^+$) that are less than or equal to n ($i \le n$). For example, $I_3 = \{1,2,3\}$ because 1, 2, and 3 are the positive numbers less than or equal to 3. Without using the notation, one might say the same thing by writing
$$I_n = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$$ 
$A$ is a finite set if we can make a bijection $ A \to \{1, \ldots, n\} $ for some $n$. For example, the set $A = \{22, 37, 65\}$ is finite because the function $f$ defined by 
$$f(22) = 1, f(37) = 2, f(65) = 3$$
Is a bijection from $A$ to $I_3 = \{1,2,3\}$

Answer (score 1):

So $I_n=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$.  For instance, $I_5=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.    Each of these $I_n$ sets give a standard-sized finite set.  In order for a set to be finite it must be equinumerous with one of these standard finite sets (or it must be empty).

Comment: Thanks for the response, so basically for a set to be finite it must have a number of elements that can be represented by a natural number i.e. 7 elements or 120?

Comment: Right.  And that means it can be matched with one of the standard finite $I_n$ sets (or it is empty).

Answer (score 0):

Let A be a non-empty set. Note that the two statements given below are equivalent (in ZFC):

1. Every Injection from A to A is a Surjection.
2. Every Surjection from A to A is an Injection.
   Now A is said to be finite off it satisfies (1) [and thus (2)].
   However this definition is not intuitive and doesn't include the case of empty set. But it doesn't involve the concept of natural numbers directly.

Comment: Reference: Ramji Lal's Algebra Vol. 1